# Adding a new row with additional value in only one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame as follows:

```
Name | Year | Score | Time
Bob   2000   5       8
Jan   2000   6       6
Bob   2001   4       7
Jan   2001   8       8
Carl  2001   2       4
Bob   2002   5       7
Jan   2002   6       9
Carl  2002   7       4
```

As you can see, Carl has no entry for `Year` = `2000`. I want to create a new row with that give Carl an entry in `Year` = 2000, but my actual DataFrame has 42 feature. What is the easiest method to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df = df.set_index(['Name','Year']).unstack(fill_value=0).stack().reset_index()
print (df)
   Name  Year  Score  Time
0   Bob  2000      5     8
1   Bob  2001      4     7
2   Bob  2002      5     7
3  Carl  2000      0     0
4  Carl  2001      2     4
5  Carl  2002      7     4
6   Jan  2000      6     6
7   Jan  2001      8     8
8   Jan  2002      6     9
```